# How to get DocumentReferences in array inside a Document

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, google-cloud-functions

Very new to await/async pattren in cloud functions. Have a cloud functions that fetches data from a doucment which has an array of DocumentReferences

```
/* Create  new Chilla for a given date  */
exports.createNewSalikChilla = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const email=req.body.email;
    const date=req.body.date;

    console.log('Creating chilla for  Salik <' + email + '> on <' + date + '>');

    const db = admin.firestore();
    const habits = [];
    const salikRef = db.collection('saliks').doc(email);
    const salik = await salikRef.get();

    if (!salik.exists) {
        throw new Error("Salik not found for <" + email + ">");
    }

    const assignedHabits = salik.data()['assigned_habits'];

    assignedHabits.forEach(element => { 
       //LOST on how to get these Document Reference and push to habits = []
    });

    res.send({status: "Success"});
});
```

The document  in the saliks collection has the following structure on firestore

```
assigned_habits<array>:
                        0:
                            habit<reference>: /habits/first
                            required<number>: 200
                        1:
                            habit<reference>: /habits/second
                            required<number>: 4
name: "Hani Q"
```

But have tried everything and can't seem to figure out how to use async/await here to get all the DocumementReferecnce from the array and push to Habit Array and then after all is done i send back res.send({status: "Success"});

**Answer**

Below worked after implementing the accepted answer

```
const assignedHabits = salik.data()['assigned_habits'];
const habits_data = (await Promise.all(assignedHabits.map(element => element.habit.get())))
                    .map(snapshot => snapshot.data());

console.log(habits_data);

res.send({status: habits_data});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to wait for a bunch of asynchronous operations, you'll want to use `Promise.all()`. In your case that'd look something like:

```
const assignedHabits = salik.data()['assigned_habits'];

const habits = await Promise.all(assignedHabits.map(element => element.habit.get()));

res.send({status: "Success"});
```

The above code assumes that `habit` is a `DocumentReference` field type.